# How can we configure the local Gitlab server and how it can be accessed or clone project by person who is sitting offshore?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, setup-project, localserver

We would like to setup the Gitlab repository for our project on local ubuntu server 16.04. like described here: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/how-run-your-own-git-server/

But since its a local setup, what **external_url** should we have to configure ? Do we need setup the static IP address so that it can be accessed via internet ?

And that project should be able to clone/push/pull by the customer who is offshore, somewhere outside the network.

We are new to the Git. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!!

Answer (score 0):

Hi this can be done by two ways:

1. You can install your own GitLab by following the instructions [here](https://about.gitlab.com/install/). This will be your local installation and you can use this on your intranet too. You just need to set the `external url` in the `gitlab.rb` file. You can find the configurations [docs here.](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html)
2. The other way is you can use [GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com) and can create your repository for this purpose. In this case you don't need to worry about the infrastructure. That project will be accessible to anyone who has access to it and they clone/push/pull if they have permission.

Comment: thanks for response, we want to setup Gitlab like you described in 1st option but my question is how it can be accessed from other network. The link you said, talks about configuration of "external url" that's right but that is only accessible over internet to the people on same network. Do i need to configure the static IP for this ?